# How to cut array by total column and make new array for the other

Tags: php, arrays

I have array example :

```
array(21) {[0]=>1 [1]=>"AAA" [2]=>"BBB" [3]=>"CCC" [4]=>"DDDD" [5]=>"EEE" [6]=>"FFF" [7]=>2 [8]=>"GGG" [9]=>"KKK" [10]=>"LLL" [11]=>"MMM" [12]=>"NNN" [13]=>"OOO" [14]=>3 [15]=>"PPP" [16]=>"QQQ" [17]=>"RRR" [18]=>"SSS" [19]=>"TTT" [20]=>"UUU" }
```

and, cut by 7 column and create new array, example :

```
array(21) {[0]=>1 [1]=>"AAA" [2]=>"BBB" [3]=>"CCC" [4]=>"DDDD" [5]=>"EEE" [6]=>"FFF"} 
array(21) {[0]=>2 [1]=>"GGG" [2]=>"KKK" [3]=>"LLL" [4]=>"MMM" [5]=>"NNN" [6]=>"OOO"}
array(21) {[0]=>3 [1]=>"PPP" [2]=>"QQQ" [3]=>"RRR" [4]=>"SSS" [5]=>"TTT" [6]=>"UUU"}
```

So,How to cut array by total column and make new array for the other?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data expecting every 7th item to be the end of a set, you can make use of [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
$output_array = array_chunk( $input_array, 7);
```